# C# Persistent Connection To SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am programming a C# TCP service. In this service clients connects to our TCP server
to gets or writes some data.

The problem:

In the morning we restart our database server and the service loses the connection to the
database. When the next request comes in our system there is no database connection anymore.

Does somebody knows what I can do?

How can I keep or reconnect to the database server after the restart?

Comment: Create & open a new connection each time you need to do something on the database. Why exactly are you maintaining a persistent connection? What requirement does it solve?

Comment: I thinked that it needs more time to reconnect all the time. But now I see that it doesn't make a big performance difference, because of the connection pooling.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I think it is better not to maintain an open SqlConnection to the sql database during all the service lifetime.

Instead, instanciate a SqlConnection object, open it, process your query, then close it: it will use the internal [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) mechanism of SQL server.

For example, you can enclose each queries in a block of code that Opens and Closes the connection :

```
using(var cn = new SqlConnection(csString))
{
    cn.Open();

    ... // your query

    cn.Close();
}
```

By this way, when the database restarts nightly, it will be transparent for you.

Comment: Isn't the Close() call redundant here because it will be called when the using block closes?

Comment: Yes it is, but I prefer to keep it for stupid reason: if I remove it, the lone cn.Open() method makes the code too ugly for me.